# Associate array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a associate array in javascript that is accessible in whole page:
and declared that as given below

```
     search = [];
     window.search = [];
```

and pushing the key-value pair like this:

```
window.search.push({'locations': 'New Delhi'}); 
console.log(window.search);
```

and getting the console like this:

```
[Object]0: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

but I want to store value in key-pair format in this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an associative array in javascript. And what you were creating was just an array of objects. What you are looking for is an object. Which the key-value pairs are just object property names and values.

```
//Literal object notation
var myObj = {
    "somekey":"somevalue",
    "otherkey": 33
};
console.log(myObj);

//Using dot notation
var myObj = {};
myObj.somekey = "somevalue";
myObj.otherkey = 33;
console.log(myObj);

//Using array like notation
var myObj = {};
myObj["somekey"] = "somevalue";
myObj["otherkey"] = 33;
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Key-Value like: `window.search['key'] = value;`

I think you want something like this:

```js
window.search = {};
window.search['location'] = 'New Delhi';

console.log( window.search );
```

Comment: I want t push key-value pair in this Its not like what I need.

Comment: @RaghavSingh well, there is no "associtive array" in JavaScript. If you want a collection of Key - Value pair, it must be an Object.